# unable to add java class in rft

Tags: java, selenium, rft

I have a ready selenium script created in eclipse that's a java class with all need full code.

I just want to add the code to RFT script and run it from RFT. I have tried adding the superclass in script. But i was unable to call the class that is internally called in the java class.I know i am bit confusing with question.

So for ex.. I have
`USerEndChatClass.java` calling `CreateFolder.java` class used internally to create folder. So if i want to use both of them in a script can i do it.

Step wise details to do it will be very helpful. :)

Note :- I had added the need full library under build path of project.

Thanks in Advance
**Learner** :)

Comment: Have a careful read through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and improve your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks , Right it seems i am not clear.. i will get back with complete frame.